# How to manually upgrade iTunes library to Music.app library on macOS Catalina?

Tags: itunes, music, catalina, music.app

I have a smaller iTunes library on an internal SSD and larger one on an external drive.

I have upgraded to macOS Catalina.
The smaller music library has been upgraded, the larger one hasn't.

**How can I force the second library to upgrade to Music.app library format too?**

[image: example of empty Music.app library]

Comment: What happens if you hold `⌥ opt` while launching Music?

Comment: Holding `Option` while launching Music.app shows the classic dialog for opening a library from filesystem (same as in iTunes), which is nice, this wasn't possible in macOS Catalina Beta (when I was trying this for the first time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Quit Music.app by `Cmd`+`Q`
2. Hold `Option` key and start Music.app
3. `Choose music library` dialog opens. Click `Choose library...`
4. Locate the old `.itl` file (e.g. `Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl`) and select it
5. Input a name for a new library and click Save
6. Music.app starts with original library contents within a few seconds. Only a few megabyte large library is created on the disk. Media files and iTunes files are left intact.
7. Optional: go to Music.app preferences - `Files` tab and check the settings, so you know which location is currently used for media files.

Note: This didn't work in beta versions of macOS Catalina – first versions of Music.app didn't support multiple libraries or selecting a library.

Good to know to avoid confusion while working with multiple libraries: double-clicking on `.itl` file, or `.musiclibrary` library (folder) from Finder opens Music.app with the last used library. It does NOT switch the library.

Comment: This seems to not move any of the underlying music files. File > Library > Organize Library also does not appear to do anything. If I want to make a consolidated directory with everything in it, how can I do that?

Comment: In case this helps anyone: I had an `iTunes Library` file with no extention and one with a `.xml` extension. The right one to use in the conversion is the one without an extension (you have to manually rename it in Finder).

Comment: In order to actually move the library's files, you can change the location in the Music.app preferences *Files* tab. There, you can set a new location and Music.app will ask whether to move the files. Accepting, will not really move the files. But you can open *File* → *Library* → *Organise Library…* and check *Consolidate files*. This will actually copy (not move!) the files to the new location. (Tested on Big Sur)